# IIS 8 localhost page not loading on Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, localhost, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I am currently trying to open a webapp from IIS 8 on a VM using Windows Server 2012, I was previously getting error pages and I think I have fixed all those problems. Now when I click browse it opens chrome and says loading but the page never loads.

I ran the exact same project though IIS 8 on Windows 8 and it worked perfectly. The project was originally created using Visual Studios 2012 and it ran perfectly from there too, on Window 8. I have tried everything I can think of.

Does anyone have any suggestions?? Thanks